# Angular2 can I get the validators set on a form control?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I wrote a custom control component and I want to get which validators are set on it. I want te get which validators are set so I can add a `*` for a required field for example. I am using template driven form.

Is this possible and how?

My Component:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'input-text2',
    templateUrl: './input-text2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['/input-base2.scss', './input-text2.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, multi: true, useExisting: InputText2Component }
    ]
})
export class InputText2Component extends InputBase2 implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

    private ngControl: NgControl;


    value: string;
    valueChange: (value: any) => void;
    _onTouched: (value: any) => void;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
    }

    ..//other methods
}
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ql3SXNY7CysP143GoQ5?p=preview)

[Second plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I649mnZyDG5tloydlrnx?p=preview)

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding these constructor dependencies to your component should get you the validators.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
```

```
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) private validators, 
            @Optional() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) private validators) {}
```

The `FormsModule` should export these tokens.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kEu5qxjBQe37So8641zX?p=info)

Comment: Hi, I can't get it to work. I added my component. Could you provide me with an example?

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker with your code (minimal amount of code) and I try to complete it by making the validators available. The "new" button in Plunker editor provides an up-to-date ready-to-use Angular2 TS template.

Comment: I added the plunker link

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Plunker :) I updated my answer. Sorry, I had mixed in some Dart code. Instead of `this.` it should be `private `. Also the `ReactiveFormsModule` is required and `NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS` needs an `@Optional()` decorator because by default it seems there are not async validators provided.

Comment: I got it working but I got the following error: `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./MyComponent class MyComponent - inline template:16:16 caused by: No provider for Token NgValidators!` Any idea why?

Comment: Did you add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` to the imports?

Comment: Yes I did. It happens on a custom validator. See my second plunker.

Comment: You need to add `RequiredValidator` to `declarations` https://plnkr.co/edit/MVmbDntFdZZUaS1R0tdK?p=info (`ReactiveFormsModule` is not required in your Plunker example).